# Parsing multiple dates from a sentence - Python

Tags: python, string, date, datetime, reddit

I need to parse multiple dates and numbers from a single sentence, for example

Repay $1000, $250 every 2 weeks 01/13-02/24/2023

however there need to be 100s of lines read like this and all are in different formats, some may have the installation amounts written first or not at all, some only put one or two dates others none at all.
I was planning on using multiple string manipulation commands to do this but that would be too inconsistent.
Is there a more optimised way to do this by any chance?

I'm using the reddit api to pull the post titles

this is the base code for finding the initial return amount

```
repayment = re.findall(r"\B[$/€/£]\d+", df1["Return_Amount"].values[0].lower())
y = list(map(str, repayment))
if len(y) > 1:
    return_amt = y[1]
    return_amt = return_amt[1:]
    return_amt = int(return_amt)
    df1["Return_Amount"].values[0] = return_amt
```

there are too many variations for string manipulation to effectively work on them all

Comment: It would be useful to add more information... for example it is unclear what "df1["Return_Amount"].values[0].lower()" is

Comment: how is your desired output should look like?